# Showing rational numbers are algebraic

Tags: number-theory

A polynomial with integer coefficients is an expression of the form:
$f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$

where $a_n$, $a_{n-1}, \ldots, a_1, a_0$ are integers and $a_n$ is not equal to $0$.

a zero of the polynomial is a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=0$

A real number is said to be algebraic if it is a zero polynomial with integer coefficients

1) Show that every rational number is algebraic

2) Show that if $a$, $b$ and $k$ are positive integers, then the $k$-th root of $a/b$ is algebraic

I don't even know where to start on this.  What is a zero of a polynomial with integer coefficients?

Comment: What is the simplest polynomial equation with integer coefficients that has $2/3$ as a root?

Comment: Consider the polynomial x-1, 2x-1, x-2 as a few examples of what are the zeroes for these and what can this tell you about generating a polynomial for a given fraction?

Comment: A zero of a polynomial with integer coefficients is just what you said it was in your question, when you typed "a zero of the polynomial is a, C is in R such that f(c)=0".  Except that you shouldn't be changing notation in midstream from capital $C$ to lower-case $c$.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand what an algebraic number is? Do you know how to show that $\frac{3}{5}$ is algebraic?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I don't know anything about this.  No, I don't know what an algebraic number is.  I don't know how to show 3/5 as algebraic either.

Comment: Do you know what a zero of a polynomial is (AKA, a root of a polynomial)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rational number $5/7$ is a zero of the polynomial $7x+(-5)$.  We have $n=1$, $a_1=7$, $a_0=-5$.

So try showing that works with *every* rational number.

Comment: How would I do that?  Would I call 5 = to a and 7 = to b and say that it is true for a+1/b+1?

Comment: It seems to me you are confused about far more than this one problem.  A rational number is a number that can be written as an integer over another integer, i.e. $a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers.  If $x=a/b$, i.e. if $x$ is rational, then $bx+(-a)$ is $0$, so $x$ is a zero of the polynomial $bx+(-a)$, and $b$ and $-a$ are integer coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The polynomials you need will have very simple forms.

**Bigger hint:**

> In particular, they will all have exactly two terms.

Comment: Of course this is true, but how does it help?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, this was my best attempt at a hint that might be helpful but wouldn't give it all away.

Comment: I would rather exhibit one particular polynomial in each case, and ask to generalize. As it stands, you're saying "The solution will not be complicated." which I don't see as something helpful, rather as a motivational comment.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I don't remember specific examples, but I definitely remember times when being told that the solution is simple actually helped me find it.

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the duplicate question (posed by OP), and see that an explicit example was given, but OP didn't understand it.

Comment: This is a devious hint... actually it helps to write the polynomial in a straightforward fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to read the definition over and over.

> A complex number is said to be algebraic if there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and integers $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ with $a_n\neq0$ that $$\sum_{j=0}^na_jz^j=0$$.

To show that every rational is algebraic one needs two terms and make a simple observation on how to choose the $a$'s, as the definition says *integers* $a_j$.