# Product of Algebraic Number and Rational Number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ is an algebraic number and $b$ is a rational number, then show that $ab$ is algebraic number. My attempt is to prove it by contradiction, but it failed. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try proving all rational number are algebraic and the product of two numbers is algebraic. If you are having trouble, refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527508/showing-rational-numbers-are-algebraic and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that the sum and product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155122/how-to-prove-that-the-sum-and-product-of-two-algebraic-numbers-is-algebraic)

Comment: @JC12 The proof for the fact that product of two algebraic numbers is algebraic isn't elementary, however this question can be answer by elementary methods as in the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Let 
$$f(x)=x^n + r_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +r_1x + r_0$$
be a polynomial with rational coefficients such that $f(a)=0$.

Then
$$a^n + r_{n-1}a^{n-1} + \cdots + r_1a + r_0 = 0.$$
Multiply through by $b^n$. We get
$$b^na^n + r_{n-1}bb^{n-1}a^{n-1} + \cdots + r_1b^{n-1}ba + r_0b^n = 0.$$
Can you finish it off?

Comment: Thanks for getting me back.